# Selection.Replace doesn't replace commas with a dot

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I have a column with numbers. If I set it to TEXT format, than select it, click on Replace and replace commas with a dot, it works greatly.  My numbers get DOTS instead of COMMAS. (This is what I want, because I am not using their "numeric value").

If I record a macro when doing that, that is the generated code:

```
Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```

If I run this code on the same data (the original one, containing COMMAS, it doesn´t work. Why?

My data, just in case:

```
1.3.11
4.5.2-714156
3.1.59
4.2.2
4,3
4,3
4,3
4,3
```

Comment: Use system separators: decimal COMMA , and thousands separator DOT .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not necessarily sure why the code you've quoted isn't working. However the following should give you the outcome I believe you're trying to get:

```
Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In Selection
    Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, ",", ".")
Next
```

Comment: your answer works fine and is the simplest so far... but i am curious why the generated code by macro doesn´t work =/.  If nobody finds out, i will mark it as correct... anyway, thanks for your time =)

Answer (score 0):

I really can't explain why your code doesn't work, I have played around with it for a few minutes now and I experience the same issues (works while I macro record, doesn't work while I  re-execute macro).

This, however, succeeds at doing what you want :

```
last = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 1 To last
    Cells(x, 2) = Replace(Cells(x, 2), ",", ".")
Next x
```

This code :

1. Finds the last row in column 2
2. Replaces the commas with dots for each individual cell

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Only to discover it was not the macros that at fault but rather the two “.” under the number section of the keyboard vs the “.” in the alphabets section of the keyboard. With excel these little differences matter.